# DataGridView button column no load correctly in first load

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a method that load DataGridView as:

```
private void LoadgvList()
        {
                this.dgCustomerList.DataSource = db.GetTableBySQL(query);

//Create column

 var dgvBidButCol = new DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn()
                        {
                            Name = "btnCustomerCreateAgreement",
                            Text = "Generate",
                            HeaderText = "Agreement",
                            Width = 70,
                            UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
                        };
                        this.dgCustomerList.Columns.Add(dgvBidButCol);

//Disable or enable button depending of received values

     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgCustomerList.Rows)
                        {
                            var canHavePricingRowCells = row.Cells["CanHavePricing"].Value is null ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["CanHavePricing"].Value);
                            var currentBidToValue = ((DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)row.Cells["Bid To"]).FormattedValue.ToString();

                            if (canHavePricingRowCells is false || currentBidToValue == "No")
                            {
                                ((DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)row.Cells["btnCustomerCreateAgreement"]).Enabled = false;
                            }
                        }
            }
```

In first load every button is Enabled = true, when I refresh it by calling method again. It disabled button correctly. Why it is not disable in first load? That no make any sense. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid needs to be visible on the screen to perform this type of action, so try using the TabControl's Selected event with a BeginInvoke to force the visual update:

```
void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e) {
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgCustomerList.Rows)
    {
      var canHavePricingRowCells = row.Cells["CanHavePricing"].Value is null ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["CanHavePricing"].Value);
      var currentBidToValue = ((DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)row.Cells["Bid To"]).FormattedValue.ToString();
      if (canHavePricingRowCells is false || currentBidToValue == "No")
      {
        ((DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)row.Cells["btnCustomerCreateAgreement"]).Enabled = false;
      }
    }
  }));
}
```

Comment: What about if datagrid is in tab control? And it loads once it is clicked, what is the equivalent of OnLoad event of tab control? Regards

Comment: @Pepe For that, try the TabControl's Selected event.

Comment: I do it but same result, every button is enabled = true

Comment: @Pepe Updated the answer to include a BeginInvoke call.  That will force the code to run when the control is visible.  Worked on my test.